# Due diligence Vs Analysis

Tags: word-choice

Which word fits in best - due diligence or Analysis'

I am working with my colleague regarding some requirement and then we got a confirmation about it. Now I wanted to drop a mail to my Colleague to start working after he is sure about it.

Please perform any *(Analysis/ Due Diligence)* if required , before we proceed.

Comment: I'd say _analysis_  (with a comma after it).  Due diligence has legal overtones that may not be what you need.

Comment: Due diligence is a legal and business terms that refers to  the care that a reasonable person exercises to avoid harm to other people or their property or to the company, such as verifying things before a business deal.  You haven't provided much context, but you haven't described a situation for which due diligence would be an applicable term.  It could be, but you haven't yet described why it would be relevant.  It isn't interchangeable with "analysis"; it refers to specific kinds of situations.